# Нужны ли запятые при данном сравнительном обороте?

Tags: запятые, сравнительный-оборот

***"Он поднял его и потащил (?) как мешок (?) по земле".***

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Он поднял его и потащил, **как мешок**, по земле.*

Трехчастный оборот, сравнение относится к **дополнению**: *потащил **его, как мешок**.* Оба варианта возможны, выбор делается по структуре предложения.

Другие варианты **хуже**:

*Он поднял его и потащил, как (тащат) мешок по земле.* Придаточное сравнительная неполное.

*Он поднял его и потащил как мешок (мешком, волоком) по земле.* Интонационно практически тот же вариант, но без запятой.

Comment: А если  потащил как мешок = "потащил мешком", волоком, то есть способом, которым перетаскивают мешки, а не то, что это было похоже на мешок. Он его поднял и потащил волоком по земле.

Comment: Я как раз и говорю, что оба варианта в трехчастной конструкции возможны: можно считать обстоятельством (потащил мешком),  а можно сравнением (его, как мешок). Авторский выбор по структуре, по интонации.  Мне кажется, что сравнение на втором плане речи (с обособлением) выглядит лучше, выразительнее, интереснее.

Comment: Может нужен ещё контекст, чтобы определиться?

Comment: Возможно, хотя я не уверена. Обособление смотрится как нейтральный вариант. Сравним: Он поднял его и потащил  волоком по земле. Использование сравнения вместо обстоятельства по смыслу ничего не меняет, но придает тексту образность, эмоциональность.